# How to deserialize the following json so that the items would use english attributes?

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

The json I have is lighthouses.json

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "results": [
        {"tunnus": 2718, "nimi": "Bengtskar", "sijainti": "Rosala", "korkeus": "52"}, 
        {"tunnus": 1015, "nimi": "Soderskar", "sijainti": "Porvoo", "korkeus": "48"}, 
        {"tunnus": 2183, "nimi": "Norreskar", "sijainti": "Loimaa", "korkeus": "21"}, 
    ]
}
```

And I'd like the items to map to the class

```
public class Lighthouse {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private int height;
    
    public Lighthouse() {}
       
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getLocation() { return location; }
    public void setLocation(String location) { this.location = location; }

    public int getHeight() { return height; }
    public void setHeight(int height) { this.height = height; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About your json file , you are interested to the part labelled by `"results"` that can be deserialized to a `Lighthouse` array with the help of [`readTree`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.lang.String)) and [`treeToValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode,%20java.lang.Class)) methods :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(json).get("results");
Lighthouse[] lighthouses = mapper.treeToValue(tree, Lighthouse[].class);
```

Your `Lighthouse` class has to map the fields in your json file with the corresponding class field having a different name with the [`JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation :

```
public class Lighthouse {
    @JsonProperty("tunnus")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("nimi")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("sijainti")
    private String location;
    @JsonProperty("korkeus")
    private int height;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could I use the same idea in a custom Lighthouse deserializer?

Comment: @TimoKälviäinen You are welcome, the `Lighthouse` class will always remain the same,  could you give some other detail about the scenario involving the  custom Lighthouse deserializer ?

Comment: I was thinking about having also a Lighthouses class with a count and ArrayList<Lighthouse> properties and reading the json somewhat like
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Lighthouses lighthouses = mapper.readValue(file, Lighthouses.class);
But I guess I should also register my Lighthouse Deserializer in a module. And register the module in the object mapper 
before calling the mappers readValue method.

Comment: With `public class Lighthouses {private int count; private List<Lighthouse>results;}` your code works with no issues, no need of a deserializer.

Comment: JsonProperty annotation solved my problem perfectly. I tried it and noticed that serializing my object the json attributes are named with the original Finnish attributes. Perfect!

Comment: @TimoKälviäinen You are welcome, I noticed now I wrote my previous message without you as receiver anyway good thing you solved your problem :)